# What is causing such slow response time to changes in my geometry nodes?

Tags: edit-mode, geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

I'm following a tutorial online by another creator. I've now reached the point where I can't continue to follow the series because my Viewport lags with every change made in the Geometry Nodes. It doesn't lag when I change angles or move around the Viewport, just when an edit is made in the Nodes. I know it is the nodes because when I turn them off the problem is gone. I'm even able to animate it smoothly without the fins, but he's able to animate with them.

[image: Fish Profile]
[image: Group Input Nodes (Part 1 of tree)]
[image: Offset Nodes (Part 2)]
[image: Big Noise (Part 3)]
[image: Mid Noise (Part 4)]
[image: Small Noise (Part 5)]
[image: Group Output (Part 6)]

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm just not sure what causes the problem. As I watch the tutorial is computer continues to run smoothly so maybe it's my computer specs?
Specs:
Processor   AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX with Radeon Graphics           3.30 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB (63.4 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Please if you need any more pictures or information, please let me know, I'm not really too versed in Blender right now so I don't know what someone really needs to help.

P.S. The tutorial series is by YouTuber NENGHUO if that's relevant or helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's either hardware issue, or you didn't follow the tutorial exactly and have e.g. more subdivision levels, or just a bug, a compatibility issue etc.

To debug your setup and find out what is making it so slow, enable the "Timings":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I can get to solving it with the timings. God bless and thank you again!